# Why can't images switch?

Tags: flutter, dart

I ran into a problem: the images in the carousel do not switch. I thought that the problem was in processing the place of pressing, but the problem apparently is not in this ...

```
import 'package:awesome_extensions/awesome_extensions.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:pulse/models/profile.dart';
import 'package:pulse/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:pulse/widgets/app_image.dart';

class CarouselPhotos extends StatelessWidget {
  final Profile profile;
  final bool darkened;
  final Function(int, CarouselPageChangedReason)? callback;

  const CarouselPhotos({
    Key? key,
    required this.profile,
    this.callback,
    this.darkened = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static Offset globalPosition = Offset.zero;
  static final CarouselController controller = CarouselController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: () {
        if (globalPosition.dx > context.width / 2) {
          controller.nextPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 170));
        } else {
          controller.previousPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 170));
        }
      },
      onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
        globalPosition = tapDownDetails.globalPosition;
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            disableGesture: false,
            carouselController: controller,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: context.height - 136.h,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              onPageChanged: callback,
              scrollPhysics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
            items: List.generate(
              profile.avatars.length,
              (index) => AppImage(photo: profile.avatars[index]),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: darkened,
            child: Container(
              height: 666.h,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    AppColor.transparent,
                    AppColor.black,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the first time I have come across this widget, I have not found any solutions on the Internet, so I ask you for help

Comment: There is a lot of code in this snippet that comes from third party packages, so it's going to be difficult for anyone not familiar with each and every one of those packages to give you a good answer. I'd suggest reducing your example to a [mcve] to eliminate all of the parts of the code that are not relevant to the problem. (And in doing so, you may even discover the issue on your own.)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't enable autoplay.
So if you want to change the image automatically then make

```
autoPlay: true.
```

if you want.  to make this process start from the beginning instead of last to fast then

```
reverse: false,
```

your final code should be like this:

```
import 'package:awesome_extensions/awesome_extensions.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:pulse/models/profile.dart';
import 'package:pulse/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:pulse/widgets/app_image.dart';

class CarouselPhotos extends StatelessWidget {
  final Profile profile;
  final bool darkened;
  final Function(int, CarouselPageChangedReason)? callback;

  const CarouselPhotos({
    Key? key,
    required this.profile,
    this.callback,
    this.darkened = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static Offset globalPosition = Offset.zero;
  static final CarouselController controller = CarouselController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
    if (globalPosition.dx > context.width / 2) {
      controller.nextPage(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 170));
    } else {
      controller.previousPage(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 170));
    }
  },
  onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
    globalPosition = tapDownDetails.globalPosition;
  },
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        disableGesture: false,
        carouselController: controller,
        options: CarouselOptions(
          height: context.height - 136.h,
          viewportFraction: 1.0,
          onPageChanged: callback,
          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
          reverse: false,
          autoPlay: true,
          scrollPhysics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
        items: List.generate(
          profile.avatars.length,
          (index) => AppImage(photo: profile.avatars[index]),
        ),
      ),
      Visibility(
        visible: darkened,
        child: Container(
          height: 666.h,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                AppColor.transparent,
                AppColor.black,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```